# WPF Why button's background is blinking after press?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a `UserControl`, and added a `Button` inside it removing the `Background` and `Text` properties:

```
<Button x:Name="Button"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Height="40"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Width="40"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0,-2"
        Margin="0,0,0,0"
        BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
        Click="Button_Click"
        Background="{x:Null}"/>
```

I also hadled the `Button` `Click` event as below:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button.Content = new cross();
}
```

The above code fills the `Button` content with another `UserControl` which is a simple cross pic.

I have placed the `UserControl` with the `Button` into a MainWindow app and after pressing `Button`, it starts blinking - background is fluently changing between two colours. Beside my functionality from code works good. I just don't know how to get rid of that blinking background.

Before click:
[image]
After click:
[image]
[image]

Comment: This appears to be standard Windows 7 behaviour (if you have the Aero theme selected in your personal settings) and is a duplicate question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928099/button-control-keeps-flashing-after-it-has-been-clicked-and-handled-the-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `Focusable="False"` at your `Button` to achive this.

But you should read about the `Focusable`property in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if it's ok for you. I guess you can't focus the `Button`using the tab key anymore. But maybe that's not a problem for you.